# What is the best way to gracefully fail in AngularJS when no access to AJAX?

Tags: angularjs

I have an AngularJS site which has a number of DIV areas on it.

Each of these areas gets data via an AJAX feed.

Depending on the rights of the person logged in, some areas will be able to get data and others won't.

**What is the best way to gracefully show a message or just hide the specific area if that area is not allowed to get its data that it needs to show?**

I'm thinking there would be something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="contentWrapper" ng-show="userHasAccess()">  
...
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
app.controller('customerController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.userHasAccess = function () {
        $http.get(...);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function will return a promise object in her best case or nothing in another

A cleaner solution would be:

Div:

```
<div class="contentWrapper" ng-show="userHasAccess">  
...
</div>
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('customerController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.userHasAccess = false;
    $scope.getAccess = function () {
        $http.get(...).success(function(result) {
               $scope.userHasAccess = true;
        }).error(function(error) {
               $scope.userHasAccess = false;
        });;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you can't have access/possibility/whatever to associate user's access rights with areas, over wise best way will be something like this:

```
<div ng-if="user.haveAccessToThisDiv">
   //data here
</div>
```

anyway you'll have some variable where you store data from `$http` respone:

```
$http.get(...).success(function(data){
    $scope.someDivData = data;
}).error(function(err){
    //error handling here
    $scope.someDivData = null;
});
```

and html will be like:

```
<div class="contentWrapper" ng-show="someDivData">  
    {{someDivData}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you throwing correct http error response codes from your AJAX calls? If so then this approach becomes very viable:

**Create a new factory:**

```
app.factory('HttpInterceptor', function($q) {
    return function (promise) {
        return promise.then(function (response) {
            return response;
        },
        function (response) {
            if (response.status === 405) {
                // Display a nice message to the user and do something here
            }
            return $q.reject(response);
        });
    };
});
```

Then in your app **config**:

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeController'
    })
    .otherwise({
        templateUrl: 'views/404.html'
    });

    $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push('HttpInterceptor');
})
```

Basically this will give you a place to capture all your http requests and filter them appropriately, so if you wanted to capture any 500 server errors, you could do so easily.