# How to get AngularJS to conditionally not execute any code in a div?

Tags: angularjs

Thanks to the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27530070/what-is-the-best-way-to-gracefully-fail-in-angularjs-when-no-access-to-ajax), I was able to make a DIV that gets its data from an AJAX call and if it receives an Error 401 from the backend, it will gracefully display a nice message.

However, I notice that when it gets a 401 error, even though it hides the div that displays the data that it would have received, I still see in Firebug that it is tries to display this data.

**How can I tell AngularJS to not only hide this area but not execute anything in it at all?**

```
<div class="pageContent">
    <h2>Showcase AngularJS 4</h2>

    <div ng-app="mainApp">
        <div ng-controller="projectManagerController">
            <div class="projectManagerArea">
                <div class="hasAccess" ng-show="projectManagers != '[noAccess]'">
                    <h3>Project Managers</h3>
                    <ul ng-repeat="projectManager in projectManagers | orderBy: 'surname'">
                        <li>{{projectManager.surname}}</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="hasNoAccess" ng-show="projectManagers == '[noAccess]'">
                    (no access to project managers)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module('mainApp', []);
        app.controller('projectManagerController', function ($scope, $http) {
            $scope.message = 'Here are the project managers:';

            $http.get("<?= qsys::getFullUrl("task/showcaseAngularjs3") ?>")
                    .success(function (response) {
                        $scope.projectManagers = response;
                    })
                    .error(function (error) {
                        $scope.projectManagers = '[noAccess]';
                    });
        });
    </script>

    <style type="text/css" scoped>
        .projectManagerArea {
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            background-color: #eee;
            width: 500px;
            padding: 10px;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }
        .projectManagerArea h3 {
            font-size: 14px;
            margin: 0;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
        }
    </style>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use ng-if instead of ng-show. Ng-show merely uses CSS to hide the DOM element, but still tries to create it, whereas ng-if will re-create the div whenever 'projectManagers != '[noAccess]'', and remove it when the condition isn't satisfied.

```
<div class="hasAccess" ng-if="projectManagers != '[noAccess]'">
```