# How to get div to stop blinking for a split second when its ng-if is false?

Tags: angularjs

Thanks to the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27544964/how-to-get-angularjs-to-conditionally-not-execute-any-code-in-a-div), I don't get a JavaScript error when AngularJS gets a 401 error back from AJAX since I replaced `ng-show` with `ng-if`.

However, even with `ng-if`, when AJAX returns a 401 error and the `hasNoAccess` div is displayed, I notice that when the page loads, the `hasAccess` div blinks quickly on the screen and then disappears.

How can I get the `hasAccess` div to stop displaying for a split second on page load when its `ng-if` condition is false?

***ADDENDUM***: I can put a `style="display:none"` in the `hasAccess` div, which solves the problem, but then, when the `ng-if` if true, it doesn't display the div at all.

***EDIT***: Added `ng-cloak` to the `hasAccess` element, but it still blinks.

```
<div class="pageContent">
<h2>Showcase AngularJS 4: Interactivity with Bootstrap</h2>

<div ng-app="mainApp">
    <div ng-controller="projectManagerController">
        <div class="projectManagerContainer">
            <div ng-cloak class="hasAccess" ng-if="projectManagers != '[noAccess]'">
                <div class="projectManagerArea">
                    <h3>Project Managers</h3>
                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>First Name</th>
                            <th>Last Name</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr ng-repeat="projectManager in projectManagers| orderBy: 'surname'">
                            <td class="text-right">{{projectManager.id}}</td>
                            <td>{{projectManager.givenname}}</td>
                            <td>{{projectManager.surname}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <button class="btn btn-success">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>&nbsp;Edit
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="hasNoAccess" ng-if="projectManagers == '[noAccess]'">
                <div class="alert alert-warning">No access to project managers.</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    var app = angular.module('mainApp', []);
    app.controller('projectManagerController', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.message = 'Here are the project managers:';

        $http.get("<?= qsys::getFullUrl("task/showcaseAngularjs3") ?>")
                .success(function (response) {
                    $scope.projectManagers = response;
                })
                .error(function (error) {
                    $scope.projectManagers = '[noAccess]';
                });
    });
</script>

<style type="text/css" scoped>
    .pageContent {
        margin: 10px;
    }

    .projectManagerContainer {
        width: 500px;
    }
    .projectManagerArea {
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        background-color: #eee;
        padding: 20px;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
    .projectManagerArea h3 {
        font-size: 22px;
        margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Did you try use ngCloak on hasAccess div?

Comment: I put `ng-cloak` in the `hasAccess` div but it still blinks.

Comment: I would have make it display none initially..

Comment: I tried changing the `hasAccess` div to `display:none` but then when the `ng-if` is true, it doesn't display at all, as if AngularJS does not override the `display:none`.

Comment: Have you read up on `ngCloak` on the Angular.js docs? It mentions, that `ngCloak` works most effeciently, if the angular sources are loaded in the `<head>` of your page (the opposite of recommended javascript loading, duh), or if you manually add the `ngCloak` css rule, also in your `<head>` of your page. For more info, look [here](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.7/docs/api/ng/directive/ngCloak)

Comment: use ng-cloak in body tag.